# Access IP of docker container at runtime

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid, docker-network

I have cross browser tests that I have written with selenium. Since I want to test multiple browsers on multiple platforms I use docker virtualization and selenium grid. I could execute my tests without docker via localhost:4444 with this `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    environment:
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 16
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 3000
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 3000

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    container_name: web-automation_chrome
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 4
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 4
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9001:5900"

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    container_name: web-automation_firefox
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 2
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 2
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9002:5900"

  opera:
    image: selenium/node-opera
    container_name: web-automation_opera
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 2
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 2
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9003:5900"
```

I just executed my tests with maven and they would succeed. Then I planned to containerize also my browser JUnit tests and created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11 as build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

COPY .git .git
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY wait-for-it.sh .
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "wait-for-it.sh"]
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src

RUN ./wait-for-it.sh hub:4444 -- ./mvnw clean package

FROM openjdk:11
VOLUME /tmp
COPY --from=build /workspace/app/target/*.jar app.jar
```

Which should work fine as well and added this part to my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    depends_on:
      - "hub"
```

As soon as I run `docker-compose up`, the maven builds the tests successfully and selenium grid is set up successfully but I receive the following error:

```
[ERROR] loginUserNotExistentFirefox  Time elapsed: 0.033 s  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '7e67c412b3c0', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.121-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.9.1'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.seleniumtests.frontendtests.tests.TestLogin.loginUserNotExistentFirefox(TestLogin.java:29)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hub
        at org.seleniumtests.frontendtests.tests.TestLogin.loginUserNotExistentFirefox(TestLogin.java:29)
```

This is how I plan to reach the service from my `app` container.

```
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://hub:4444/wd/hub"),
                                                             DesiredCapabilities.operaBlink());
```

Comment: `Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444` - it's not *trying* to reach `hub`, you don't seem to have configured the hostname correctly.

Comment: But where have I not configured the hostname correctly? In my tests I just attempt to reach `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`
 and when I remove the test build and manually `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d` and then `mvn clean install`, the tests run perfectly fine.

Comment: You mean if you run the tests *outside* the compose network? `localhost:4444` works outside that network because of `ports: - "4444:4444"`, which exposes that port from the container on your host, but *inside* the network you need to use the service name (`hub`) as the hostname.

Comment: Okay I changed the URLs in the cases to `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://hub:4444/wd/hub")` and now I receive an Unknown Host Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First problem: you can't connect to localhost:4444

There's a bridge (by default in Docker Compose) between your services, and you can access to another service by `<service_name>:<service_port>`, so you can access *hub* service by `hub:4444`.

### Second problem, it may be outcome when you solve the first problem

From the official Docker Compose documentation, as you can read [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/):

> You can control the order of service startup and shutdown with the depends_on option. Compose always starts and stops containers in dependency order, where dependencies are determined by depends_on, links, volumes_from, and network_mode: "service:...".

As you did with depends_on, but

> However, for startup Compose does not wait until a container is “ready” (whatever that means for your particular application) - only until it’s running. There’s a good reason for this.

#### Docker Compose official solution

> Use a tool such as [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize), sh-compatible [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for), or
> [RelayAndContainers](https://github.com/jasonsychau/RelayAndContainers) template. These are small wrapper scripts which you
> can include in your application’s image to poll a given host and port
> until it’s accepting TCP connections.

They suggest you to act like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    environment:
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 16
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 3000
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 3000

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    depends_on:
      - "hub"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "hub:4444", "--", "java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Comment: I have replaced the `test`container with your `app` container and replaced both docker version and hub. I habe kept the Dockerfile that I have provided and then tried to access http://hub:4444/wd/hub from my container but I get the UnknownHostException hub. I have also downloaded wait-for-it.sh

Comment: Thanks for noticing about the version, it wasn't intentional to change your version to 2. I edited the answer.
Can you give us the new stack trace?

Comment: `Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '12bf5131313e', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.121-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.9.1'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.seleniumtests.frontendtests.tests.TestLogin.loginUserNotExistentOpera(TestLogin.java:61)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hub: Name or service not known
        at org.seleniumtests.frontendtests.tests.TestLogin.loginUserNotExistentOpera(TestLogin.java:61)`

Comment: I think it might have something to do with `docker package`executing the tests before the wait for it is executed. Does docker first execute commands or build?

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up` only, the problem is that you have to run `docker-compose build` for rebuilding your image, and then `docker-compose up` again.

Comment: I'm noticing now that in your stacktrace, is written that your hostname is `12bf5131313e`. Have you tried adding `container_name: hub` in your `hub` service?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227273/discussion-between-marte-valerio-falcone-and-bojack-horseman).